# django-socialregistration and django-userena

Tags: django

I found this code to connect django-userena to socialregistration. I am new with socialregistration. What shall I do with this code?

```
from socialregistration.signals import connect as profile_connect
```

from userena.managers import ASSIGNED_PERMISSIONS

```
@receiver(socialregistration_signals.connect, sender = FacebookProfile, dispatch_uid = 'facebook.connect')
def social_connect_callback(sender, user, profile, client, **kwargs):
"""
Create a profile for this user after connecting

"""
# Create a userena user.
# TODO: You could make it prettier by setting a ``activation_key`` of ``ALREADY_ACTIVATED``
# and looking at good values for the other fields of the model.
userenaSignup = UserenaSignup.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

# Create profile for user
try:
    new_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
except:
    new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)

# Give permissions to view and change profile
for perm in ASSIGNED_PERMISSIONS['profile']:
    assign(perm[0], user, new_profile)

# Give permissions to view and change itself
for perm in ASSIGNED_PERMISSIONS['user']:
    assign(perm[0], user, user)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Django's documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions
one place where you can place this code is in models.py, in this case in userena's models.py

BTW, where did you get this code? I'm trying to connect userena with socialregistration too

**Edit:** I've found the gist on github (https://gist.github.com/1351169/) I suppose you are agiletechnologies ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how to connect django social auth (pipeline) with userena.
This 
[example](https://gist.github.com/mexekanez/0eb55cd2caf47affaa80) show how to connect social auth pipeline and userena (userena requires guardian permissions), so this example solves it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.